# Python selenium formating brackets xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm having a problem with xpath finding element I need.

Here's html code im trying to find.

```
name="itemData[analysis][0][Pd]"
```

And that's how I'm trying to find it

```
def find(driver,path):
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, path)))
return element
element = find(driver, "//input[@name='itemData[analysis].[0].[Pd]'").send_keys(1)
```

I know the problem is in how I format, the path, but I have no idea how to format it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of **XPATH** `contains` here :

```
//name[contains(@name, 'itemData[analysis][0][Pd]')]
```

or

```
//name[contains(@name, 'itemData')]
```

or

```
//name[contains(@name, 'itemData[analysis]')]
```

and so on..